# multi-language multi-site with REST API

Tags: multisite, api, multi-language, plugin-json-api, rest-api

I am creating a site with multiple sub-sites that should support multiple languages and be queryable with a REST API.

The site itself is mostly a CMS with various pages and maybe some posts for events.
The sub-sites are cities in this case, each with a different administration.
Multiple languages means that every page can (but does not have to) be translated in any language.

Being fairly new to Wordpress Development, I am not sure if and how the different components work together.

WPML seems to have [multi-site support](https://wpml.org/documentation/support/multisite-support). Apparently, there is also a [plugin connecting it](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wpml-to-wp-api) with the popular WP-REST-API.

Can somone confirm the cross-functionality by any chance? I would like to be at least somewhat sure before purchasing WPML.

Comment: See the plugin [MultilingualPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) for this job, it works very well with Multisite and is very solid. It have no problems with the REST API, you can use it for all your requirements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, WPML works well with multi-site and also with the WP-REST-API (even without further plugins).